# How to get LDAP username of a user running python script

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I need to find a LDAP username of a user running my python (2.7) script. Command line I would do it by typing `whoami` and in python I am looking for equivalent solution with python-ldap module.

Comment: I didn't understand, do you want to get current system user (the user who runs script) ?

Comment: @AhmadNourallah yes, exactly. To log the users of the script.

Comment: When you need an LDAP username, wouldn't you rather use `ldapwhoami`? According to manpages, `whoami` prints  the  user  name  associated  with the current effective user ID. While - again, according to manpages - `ldapwhoami` opens a connection to an LDAP server, binds, and performs a whoami operation. Could you provide  a code-example of what you are planning to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getuser` function from `getpass` standard library in python to get the current system user. Try this:

```
>>> from getpass import getuser
>>> getuser()
'ahmadnourallah'
```